# How to avoid using Selection and Select when going to the bottom of a column

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to stop using ActiveCell etc as StackOverflow has very much declared this a "nono"

My current code is:

```
Sub SitesAndProd()

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = Worksheets("Data")
Set rng = ws.Cells(1, 13)

    LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    rng.FormulaR1C1 = "SitesAndProd"                                              'Rename Cell SitesAndProd

Set rng = ws.Cells(2, 13)

    rng.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-12]&RC[-4]"
    rng.Offset(0, -1).Select                                                     'Move left 1 column
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select                                                        'Go to bottom of column
    rng.Offset(0, 1).Select                                                      'Move right 1 column
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select                                        'Go to top of Column
    Selection.FillDown                                                                  'Copy Formula Down "Fill"

    Selection.Copy                                                                      'Ctrl + C
    Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues                                                'Right click + V
    Application.CutCopyMode = False                                                     'Esc (stops the crawling ants


End Sub
```

When using `Selection.End(xlDown).Select` and `xlUp` later - it's not saving the range position

What's the best way to make sure the range is kept here?

When using the following:

```
Range("M2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-12]&RC[-4]"
Range("M2").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
Selection.FillDown
```

The code will pull the correct form - going left 1, to the bottom, right 1, selecting up to to the, then copying down

Any chance that someone can point me in the right direction to be able to do this without `ActiveCell`, `Selection` and `Select`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: Thanks. I've been using this a lot, but ActiveCell.Offset is quite specific and not covered in this - I was hoping for some slightly more specific help

Comment: your each and every use of `ActiveCell` simply derives from its preceeding `.Select`. Hence just avoid `Select` by means of any of those good pieces of advice you can find in the link I provided and you'll "automagically" get rid of any need of `ActiveCell`

Comment: I'm avoiding that using `With` currently. But `With rng .Offset...` Requires a `=` or `.` - where .Select is the first thing that comes to mind

Comment: Is there anything you are looking for on this code? Some code word, or value? Any pattern to get a more efficient code?

Comment: It's more a way of getting out of the habit, as I've been doing it too long. Unfortnautley I'm so used to `.Select` at the end of `Offset` that I don't know what comes next. I'm almost there using `With` however

Comment: Can you put me an example of what are you intending with this code? I could give you a different approach.

Comment: `With …` doesn't require any `=`. Take a thorough reading of given link and you'll find what you need. As a rule of thumb you can melt two consecutive codelines, the first ending with `...Select` and the second staring with `ActiveCell...` (or `Selection…`), erasing both `Select` and `ActiveCell` (or `Selection`)

Comment: Text example: Put formula in `M2`. Fill down. The best way I can do this is: go left 1, go down, go right 1, go up

Comment: The best way to do this is for example declaring a `LastRow` variable where you store the last cell with text. `LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` this would store the last row on column A which has text. Then you would use the with like: 
`With ws.Range("M2:M" & LastRow)
 .FormulaR1C1 = The Formula you need
 .Value = .Value
End With` (ws is a worksheet variable which stores the worksheet you are working on)

Comment: There might be some useful pearls of wisdom here : http://www.excelitems.com/2010/12/optimize-vba-code-for-faster-macros.html

Comment: @Damian that worked perfectly. Rather weirdly, I had the same `LastRow` declaration on my `Public` for use elsewhere. If you put your comment as an answer, I'll give it green.

Comment: @SolarMike That's a great site, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is supposing the LastRow you calculated on column A equals the same amount of rows in column M

```
Option Explicit
Sub SitesAndProd()

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, LastRow As Long

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = Worksheets("Data")
    ws.Cells(1, 13) = "SitesAndProd"
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    With ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 13), ws.Cells(LastRow, 13))
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-12]&RC[-4]"
        .Value = .Value
    End With

End Sub
```

I've tweaked some of your code. You need to declare your variables, `wb As Workbook` and `ws As Worksheet`. If workbook is the one you got your code in, use `ThisWorkbook` instead `ActiveWorkbook` you will get less errors from that.

Edit: Try to avoid as much the global variables. Pass them on your subs or functions as variables.

Comment: Is there a reason not to use the variables global, but in each sub? Thank for the answer, you basically have what I have now, minus the global declaration

Comment: One quick note `LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` might have unexpected behavior because `Rows.Count` references the active sheet which could be different from the sheet referenced by `ws`.

Comment: Because you could change the global variable in some function or procedure without noticing and it would screw all your work. These errors are harder to find... For example if you got the LastRow from another procedure, just use this `Sub SitesAndProd(LastRow As Long)` and when you need to call that procedure use `Call SitesAndProd(Variable holding ur last row)`

Comment: One last bit for you, could you just edit the answer (for others) to have `ws.Cells` please :)

Comment: I don't understand... what do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, when running it, it says `Invalid or unqualified reference` - but with `ws.Cells` instead of `.Cells` it works fine. This is on the `With ws.Range(.Cells...` line

Comment: True that! Sorry  I started using just With ws, but the code was gonna get larger and then I decided to use the whole range in the with but totally forgot to add the "ws"

Comment: I've never used .Value = .Value - how do I use this but keep leading 0's? The data is a 6 digit and a 3 digit number ,often both with at least 1 leading 0 so I need them in

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189464/discussion-between-damian-and-badja).

Answer (score -1):

I expect your code:

```
Range("M2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-12]&RC[-4]"
Range("M2").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
Selection.FillDown
```

can be replaced with:

```
Range(Range("M2"), Range("M" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Formula = "=RC[-12]&RC[-4]"
```

If the column which you would like to use to determine the last filled cell is column Q:

```
Range(Range("M2"), Range("Q" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=RC[-12]&RC[-4]"
```

Comment: This just fill `M1:M2` with the formula, it doesn't go to the bottom at all

Comment: This is precisely why selecting things is so confusing. My code detects the first and last filled cell in column M. Which column should be used to determine the last row to place the formula into? I have added an example where I used column Q